# the 'want' version of prerequisite?

Tags: synonyms

Thinking about this word: prerequisite.

Requisite (require) is associated with 'need'.  i.e. algebra is a prerequisite for calculus, so you NEED to take algebra before you take calculus.

Is there a word to describe a class that's fortuitous to take before calculus, but not necessary?  Like something you'd want to take before calculus but not required to take?

Best,
chiply

Comment: Does "recommended" get what you want?  Wrong part of speech?

Comment: Can you add a sample sentence with a blank ("____") where the word you're looking for would go?

Comment: recommended is really close, and is probably the right part of speech as requisite is an adjective and recommended can be used as an adjective.  Roger, in the sense that it's advantageous to take calculus before physics, but isn't necessary:  Noun: 'As the professor of this physics course, I assert that calculus is a (blank)', Adjective: 'I assert that calculus is a (blank) course for people taking this physics class.'

Comment: If this question is about what one should say in a course description or a syllabus, then looking for a single word might be misguided. The prospective students are likely to find it much more helpful if one spells the advice one wants to give them in a full sentence, such as 'Although X is not a formal prerequisite for this course, the students who have not taken it may find this course more challenging than those who have'. As this question seems to be more about teaching practices than the language itself, it may get better responses if asked on the Academia Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Perusing through different college websites, there are a few terms that seem to fall into this category:

http://www.mtsac.edu/admissions/register-for-classes/eligibility-for-classes.html

`advisory`

https://help.learn.utoronto.ca/hc/en-us/articles/235948947-What-is-the-difference-between-prerequisites-and-recommendations-

`recommendations`

https://www.washington.edu/uaa/advising/academic-planning/choosing-courses/tips-for-getting-into-closed-restricted-courses/

`suggested`

But colloquialy, `recommended` in my opinion is the most straightforward and understandable.

Comment: I agree with recommended for the given context.